# Valores do eixo X em negrito

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como eixar os caracteres do eixo X do gráfico abaixo em negrito?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

TCH <- data.frame(
  Período =c("Jun", "Jul"), 
  CV6654 = c(9.38, 26.14), 
  CTC9002 = c(16.27, 47.71))

df <- gather(TCH, "Variedades", "Valor", -Período)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período, levels = c("Jun", "Jul")), y = Valor, fill = Variedades)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_label(aes(label = Valor), position = position_dodge(width = 1), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan2", "lightgreen")) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "TCH", subtitle = "Ganho de peso mensal") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image: Gráfico gerado]

Answer (score 2):

Basta colocar o argumento `axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold")` dentro da função `theme`.

O argumento `axis.text.x` informa que a alteração desejada deve ocorrer nas marcações do eixo x (faça o paralelo com o argumento `axis.text.y`, também presente na criação do gráfico) e `element_text(face = "bold")` informa que tais marcações devem ser *bold* (negrito, em inglês).

O código e o gráfico com o resultado estão abaixo.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

TCH <- data.frame(
    Período =c("Jun", "Jul"), 
    CV6654 = c(9.38, 26.14), 
    CTC9002 = c(16.27, 47.71))

df <- gather(TCH, "Variedades", "Valor", -Período)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período, levels = c("Jun", "Jul")), y = Valor, fill = Variedades)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_label(aes(label = Valor), position = position_dodge(width = 1), show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan2", "lightgreen")) +
    labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "TCH", subtitle = "Ganho de peso mensal") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5), 
                axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda !

excelente!

Nesse caso o argumento axis.text.x também consegue atuar no rótulo de dados presente nas barras do gráfico?